# Accessors/Mutators vs. Constructors in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What's the difference between the two approaches below?

Condition1:

```
         String abs ="newpage";
         classA oa=new classA(abs);
```

Condition2:

```
         String abs ="newpage";

         classA oa=new classA();
         oa.setMystats(abs);
```

Comment: `oa.getMystats(abs);` should be `oa.setMystats(abs);` I guess

Comment: Whether there's a difference depends on how ClassA has implemented its constructor and the method. There is no universal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in one case you are passing the parameter to the constructor, whereas in the other class you are calling a parameterless constructor and then passing a parameter to a method.

So, the first case would have a `classA` like this:

```
class classA {
   String value;

   classA(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

... and the second would be like this:

```
class classA {
   String value;

   void getMystats(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Which is more appropriate depends on what meaning you want to give to that parameter. Loosely speaking, if an instance of your class can't exist without that value, it should be set in the constructor. If that value can be freely altered after the object has been created, then it needs a method to set it.

Comment: +1 from me. IMO the most important thing you've mentioned is the requirement for having the variable during construction of the object. If `value` is required to be initialized and `ClassA` doesn't have any meaning without it - it should be in the constructor. Constructor with parameter is a straightforward way to provide immutability to your objects (by not providing any setter method).

Answer (score 0):

```
     classA oa=new classA(abs);
```

calls a constructor of classA that takes a String parameter.

```
     oa.getMystats(abs);
```

calls getMystats method of classA that takes a String parameter.

Learn more about passing parameters to constructors and methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 0):

In condition1
You are just passing arguments to your constructor.
SO that you'll probably will save this value in a internal variable.
Example:

```
String myString;
classA(String x){
myString=x;
}
```

In condition2: 
You are passing arguments to a Method in your class, you'll probably need to do something with the parameter. Otherwise you won't pass it.

```
String myString;
classA(String x){
myString=x;
}
/**
Returns the number of time that x is myStirng.
*/
int getMystats(Stirng x){
return myString.split(x).length();
}
```